# http upgrade failed with status code 400 in jmeter websocket sampler

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I have used the websocket open connection sampler request in my project.
URL: wss://sip-qa.forestreettelco.com:11443 
while executing the jmeter script getting the Response message:"http upgrade failed with status code 400"
Please help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaoDV.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 400 description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

So my expectation is that you're sending the wrong request which doesn't match what your server expects. As it is not publicly available I cannot come up with the proper configuration, however I believe you should start with normal [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and add the following [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) to the request:

- [Connection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection): `Upgrade`
- [Upgrade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Protocol_upgrade_mechanism): `websocket`
- Whatever other headers which real browser sends like `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol`, `Sec-WebSocket-Version`, `Sec-WebSocket-Key`, etc.

The headers can be added using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/)

[image]

You can capture browser traffic using built-in [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or an external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Once you will be sending the same sequence of the same requests you should get the same responses as for the real browser.